# Angular Material 10 Date Range Picker with matDatepickerFilter

Tags: angular, angular-material

Angular Material 10 MatDateRangeInput can be used with matDatepickerFilter?

If I try this:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Label</mat-label>
  <mat-date-range-input [formGroup]="parent" [rangePicker]="picker">

    <input matStartDate formControlName="start"
           [matDatepickerFilter]="myFilter"
           readonly
           placeholder="Start">
    <input matEndDate formControlName="end"
           [matDatepickerFilter]="myFilter"
           readonly
           placeholder="End">

  </mat-date-range-input>

  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-date-range-picker touchUi #picker [disabled]="false"></mat-date-range-picker>

</mat-form-field>
```

The error is

```
NG8002: Can't bind to 'matDatepickerFilter' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using mat-datepicker, you have to import MatDatepickerModule and MatNativeDateModule is recommended to import

Comment: Yes both modules imported, in fact with a simple datepicker it works, however the problem is when I use a range datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

To add filter in mat-date-range-input you must user **dateFilter** input like bottom example:

```
<mat-form-field class="custom-filter-field" appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Date</mat-label>
    <mat-date-range-input [formGroup]="range" [rangePicker]="picker"  [dateFilter]="myFilter">
      <input matStartDate placeholder="Start date" formControlName="start">
      <input matEndDate placeholder="End date" formControlName="end" >
    </mat-date-range-input>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
  </mat-form-field>
```

And in your ts file you have to implement the filter function:

```
myFilter = (d: Date | null): boolean => {
    const day = (d || new Date()).getTime();
    return day <= this.todayDate.getTime();
  };
```

this method filter the future date and doesn't show them